# Take fraction as string input and convert to int

Tags: java, string, input, fractions

I am creating a fractions class, in my main I currently take fraction input as such

```java
System.out.println("Enter whole number");
int wholeNumber = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter numerator");
int numerator = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter denominator");
int denominator = input.nextInt();

if (wholeNumber == 0) { // using fraction class to create fraction
    fraction.setWholeFraction(numerator, denominator);
} else {
    fraction.setMixedNumber(wholeNumber, numerator, denominator);
}
```

I want to take the input as a string with this format >
x y/z

I am not allowed to use `interger.parseInt` or `valueOf`. I need to do this manually.

I created a preliminary string to int method, but it won't work for my fractions

```java
public static int stringToint( String s ) {
  int r = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
  {
    if (i > 0)
      r *= 10;

    r += s.charAt(i)-'0';
  }
  return r;
}
```

I also need to be able to validate if they have entered it in the correct format, disallow doubles, and allow negatives.

if someone can help me out I have not been able to figure this one out.

Comment: What do you mean by "It won't work for my fractions" ?

Comment: @vincrichaud meaning my stringToInt method willl covert a string to int, but im not able to use this to take input for my fractions

Comment: I don't see how you can't use it for your fraction. Go through your input until your specific character (`' '` and `/`), and put the substring (x, y and z) in your method

Comment: sorry, im not sure what you mean

Comment: Uou have to separate x, y and z in your input. for example `String x = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(' ')-1);` and `String y = input.substring(input.indexOf(' '), input.indexOf('/')-1);`, etc. And then call your method on each : `stringToInt(x);` etc

Answer (score 2):

You can use method `useDelimiter()` to separate different parts of your string.

For checking double and negative values, you can traverse through the string and check if it contains floating point `","` or negative sign `"-"`

Answer (score 0):

In case regular expressions are allowed in this task, they may be used to check formatting of the input string and parse appropriate parts.

Here, the pattern with named groups can help to get appropriate substrings which should be passed then to `stringToint`:

```java
static final Pattern FORMAT = Pattern.compile("(?<neg>[-+]?)\\s*(?<whole>\\d*)\\s*(?<nomin>\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(?<denom>\\d+)");

static void parseRational(String str) {
    
    Matcher matcher = FORMAT.matcher(str);
    
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("sign: "  + matcher.group("neg"));
        System.out.println("whole: " + stringToint(matcher.group("whole")));
        System.out.println("nomin: " + stringToint(matcher.group("nomin")));
        System.out.println("denom: " + stringToint(matcher.group("denom")));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input: " + str);
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
for (String str : Arrays.asList("-2 3/74", "2/5", "+4 / 9", "3.1415", "1.2 3.4/5.6")) {
    parseRational(str);
    System.out.println("====");
}
```

Output:

```
sign: -
whole: 2
nomin: 3
denom: 74
====
sign: 
whole: 0
nomin: 2
denom: 5
====
sign: +
whole: 0
nomin: 4
denom: 9
====
Invalid input: 3.1415
====
Invalid input: 1.2 3.4/5.6
====
```